# oracle sql developer update query

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to insert plane_id in bookhangar table where book column having value 'no'.
my bookhangar table is

```
hangar_id |  book | plane_id 
-------------------------------         
han103    |   no  | null

han104    |   yes |pla102
```

my tried query is

```
insert into bookhangar (plane_id) values('pla104') where book='no';
```

but it doesnot inserted.

I tried another query

```
update  bookhangar set plane_id='PLA104' where book='no';
```

It also doesnot work.

Comment: First, you can't use `where` clause in an insert statement except in `insert...select..where`. And what error message did you get for that update statement?

Comment: What meaning could `INSERT INTO WHERE` possibly have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will be updated if there is any row containing value 'no'

```
update  bookhangar set plane_id='PLA104' where lower(trim(book))='no';
```

Comment: wow...It is working now....Your query is working for me...Thankyou so much

Answer (score 0):

Your update should be working:

```
update bookhangar
    set plane_id = 'PLA104'
    where book = 'no';
```

If it does not, I would start by checking if this query works

```
select *
from bookhangar
where book = 'no';
```

I suspect that will return no rows.  So, try this:

```
select *
from bookhangar
where book like '%no%';
```

You will need to investigate what value is really being stored . . . perhaps it has hidden characters, such as spaces at the beginning of the string.

Comment: my table has value...and  select *
from bookhangar
where book = 'no'; the above query returns value....I got solution....The solution is  update  bookhangar set plane_id='PLA104' where lower(trim(book))='no';